# Gradle Building Errors in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to solve the Gradle error but not solve this error so you can find this solution.

- What went wrong:
  `A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_7ddlmucs2j5kiypgoiym6wbeo.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7ddlmucs2j5kiypgoiym6wbeo$_run_closure2) values: [build_7ddlmucs2j5kiypgoiym6wbeo$_run_closure2@7a5f345e]

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 624ms
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           1,242ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1`

I've been receiving the following error:

This is my current dependency. I have been trying to figure out how to resolve this error but I just can not figure it out. Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my other build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_auth"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is gonna work to you but it worked for me.

try going to android/gradle folder then find the wrapper and edit it to the latest version e.g 7.6-bin ,then go to app gradle and rename the kotlin version to 1.7.0 and the build tools to 7.4.0 like this.

```
#Fri Jan 20 16:18:48 SAST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6- 
bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

Hope its gonna help