# Flutter: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, using flutter without android studio

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I am using Windows 11 machine and learning flutter for the first time and I am using it without Android Studio. I have installed and setup the android SDK manually. Added the SDK to path. Made an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable. Using the sdkmanager I have installed the "build-tools;33.0.1" "platforms;android-33" "platform-tools". I have added flutter sdk, platform-tools to path.

I have manually installed Gradle version 8.0.2 and added it to path as well.

Now I opened VS Code, opened the command palette and selected Flutter:New Project and then selecting Application.

I ran "flutter run" in the bash terminal but received the following error:
[this is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4p36.png)

Here is my gradle version:
[gradle version 8.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7jIP.png)

Flutter Doctor output:
[I am using flutter without android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xcov.png)

I have installed jdk version 19.0.2 and added that to path as well. Added JAVA_HOME variable in the environment.

I have tried changing the version of gradle in the gradle-wrapper.properties file:
[Before the version was gradle-7.5-all.zip, so I simply changed it to gradle-8.0.2-all.zip, matching the one installed on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nCL.png)

Before the version was gradle-7.5-all.zip, so I simply changed it to gradle-8.0.2-all.zip, matching the one installed on my machine.
Due to this in my .gradle folder there are two subfolders made, which are 7.5 and 8.0.2.

I have tried deleting this folder and recompiling it, but it still doesn't work.

I have searched the web and tried multiple solutions. I ran `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` etc. etc. but none of them seem to work. What can I try next?

Here is my `root/android/app/build.gradle` script:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sampleapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried many solutions available on the internet, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think upgrade gradle version is a good idea for this. Since flutter is a cross-platform frameword, it has some limit in use latest version of gradle.

So, I can give you some recommend to fix, hope this help you that downgrade java version and gradle version

```
SampleApp
- android
  - app
  - build.gradle
- gradle
  - gradle-wrapper.properties
build.gradle
```

As you can see, we have two build.gradle file seperately,
You should downgrade version in project/build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        ...
    }
```

And in gradle-wrapper.properties, you should downgrade version, too

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Then in terminal, you call `flutter clean` and `flutter run` to build again.
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter doctor -v`. This will give you much more detailed info about your environment.

But I recommend you use Android Studio so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel. It's much easier to start out on and can save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered another guy with the same problem as yours, I guess it's gonna work as it worked for me Check this , [I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75635750/20281089)

Comment: Thanks Karl, this solution has worked, its the compatibility issue of Gradle with Java.